# How to overwrite the CSV data set config path in JMeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

My requirement is, JMeter should read the different csv file path instead of the path is mentioned in CSV data set config.

Example :
Currently, we configured CSV data set config under Threadgroup1. It is reading the csv files from this path c://Jmeter/testing.csv.

Once the test starts, i need to instruct JMeter to read the csv files from different path c://dummy/testing.csv.

I have tried the JSR223preprocessor with below code but still Threadgroup1 is reading the username from original path.

`String Uid = ${__CSVRead(c://dummy/testing.csv,0)} vars.put("pUserid",Uid);` 
May i know how to achieve this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

This scenario is "not achievable", at least not with [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)

Take a look at [JMeter test elements execution order](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder):

```
0. Configuration elements
1. Pre-Processors
2. Timers
3. Sampler
4. Post-Processors (unless SampleResult is null)
5. Assertions (unless SampleResult is null)
6. Listeners (unless SampleResult is null)
```

So CSV Data Set Config being a [Configuration Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) is being initialized **before anything else**

If you want to read data from CSV file and provide the filename dynamically you can either use [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy).